# appengine remote api unable to login

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I go to appengine.google.com/a/mydomain.com i am able to login and
see all my apps and administer them.

However, when I try to use the remote_api the same username/password does not work.

I'm using the interactive console code from http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html

Comment: Are you using a Google Apps For Your Domain (or whatever it's called) to log into the App Engine administration views?

Comment: Yes. I go to appengine.google.com/a/mydomain.ocm I have setup google apps for mydomain.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue with Google Accounts authentication. If you created an app and set it to use Google Accounts for authentication, and you yourself use a Google Apps account, you will not be able to authenticate against your app as an administrator using that account, even if you've created a Google Account for that email address. The workaround for now is to create a gmail account and add it as an administrator of your app, using that whenever you need to authenticate against your app as an administrator. You can still use your existing account for deployments and to log in to the admin console.

It's a pain, I know - I run into it every day myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue while developing for GAE on google apps. To make it work, I've created a simple wrapper around a snippet provided by Nick (blog.notdot.net - I can't seem to find the proper reference right now) that has been working for me. You can find it [here](http://github.com/caio/bizarrice/blob/master/remote_console.py).

Comment: I couldn't find remote_console.py but I tried to use the remote_api_shell.py at github.com/caio/bizarrice/ but get the same error. appcfg.py update works fine and it accepts my apps for domain email id and password.